# Yii - ajax call on mouseover and get Data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, yii

**Index File**

```
        <h4>Dates</h4>
            <?php 
                foreach($dates as $date){
                    echo TbHtml::ajaxButton(date("D, d M" ,strtotime($date->date)),
                        array(
                            'matches/countryVenue'
                        ),
                        array(
                            // 'dataType'=>'json',
                            'type'=>'POST',
                            'data'=>array('id'=>$date->id),
                            'success'=>'js: function(data) {
                                alert(data);
                            }',
                            'failure'=>'js: function(data) {
                                   alert("error");
                            }',
                        ),
                        array(
                            "id"=>$date->id,
                            "onmouseover"=>"date(this.id);"
                        )
                    );
                    echo "<br>";
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

**JS Code**

```
 <script>
     function date(x){
         //alert("Date " + x);
      };
  </script>
```

**Matches Controller File** :

```
 public function actionCountryVenue(){
         if(isset($_POST['id'])){
                $id = $_POST['id'];
         }
        // echo $id;

             $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
             $criteria->select = "*";
             $criteria->condition = "DATE = ".$id;
             $countryVenue = Matches::model()->findAll($criteria);

             if(!empty($countryVenue)){
                echo CJSON::encode(array('countryVenue'=>$countryVenue));
             }
        }
```

**My Question**

I need help from someone to give an exact idea of callback and ajax.

Moreover what I plan to do is `onmouseover` of the `ajaxButton`, I want to make an ajax call sending the ID of the button to the controller and return json data from the controller and convert into php array.

**Edit Info**

I have managed to send the data from the controller to the index file but can not render json data in php.

Comment: Did you debug it? I see some problems: What if $id is not received it? What happens if there's no countryVenue? What's date format? If you answer me this I can provide a solution.

Comment: @Skatox        `$id` is recieved by the controller and the query runs. `$countryVenue` is the dataProvider for the fetched records and it does recieve data when the query is fired. Date Format is pretty much irrelevant just for display purpose. I do not know how to `CJSON Decode` and convert it to php array from the js code.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by CJSON Decode, you don't need to decode it at JS code, you will receive the object data.countryVenue